# DOS pauses in stdout/execution

Tags: windows, command-line

I've been having this odd issue recently where my command line screens will basically lock the programs writing to them until I give mouse focus to the DOS window and then perform some keyboard action.

So, for example: I'll start a Tomcat instance and at some point, it simply stops updating -- I hit reload and nothing happens, nothing outputs to the Catalina window. Or, I'll check out something from SVN and it will appear to lag, but as soon as I interact with it, the lag stops.

### Edit

---

My aplogies, I used the word "screen" when I meant "window" (that is fixed).

The command (to start Tomcat):

```
C:\liferay\binaries\liferay-portal-5.2.3\tomcat-5.5.27\bin>startup.bat
```

The command to checkout a repository (in Cygwin):

```
$ svn checkout <repository>
```

To the requests to change the operating system, I say "no". At no point have I mentioned which operating system I was using, I simply stated that I was using DOS (common use implies MS, but the comments stated that I have incorrectly stated which OS I was using). Since this problem has never exhibited itself in anything other than that environment, it is not intuitive to say that this is a `Windows` problem.

Comment: "Focus on the screen": This isn't DOS.  What operating system is it?

Comment: You are not running Tomcat under DOS. Edit your question to state your real operating system and real software including versions for your terminal emulator and shell.

Comment: Do you start this program from the command line, shortcut, or some other way?  If from the command line or shortcut, please post this info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, when you selecting text in a in a command-prompt/console windows, the console application will be "locked" until your selection is done (press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>) or canceled (press any key else).

If **QuickEdit** mode of a command prompt window is ON, you'll probably enter selecting text state by a single mouse click in the client area of command prompt window. This is a misoperation often occured if **QuickEdit** mode is ON.

If you're in the above situation, you can simply turn **QuickEdit** mode OFF to avoid this misoperation.

Comment: [These are not "DOS prompt" windows.](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/a-cli-is-not-a-dos-prompt.html)  And you've assumed something not in the question, that the rest of us have instead asked to be supplied.

Comment: @JdeBP Actually, they are. While you may not like the reference, the common name for the cmd.exe program is "DOS prompt" (especially since MS commonly refers to it as such). I'll give you that Cygwin is not exactly the same thing, but since I've no idea what to call it, I used the closest approximation.

Comment: You are conflating _common_ with _incorrect_.  No, Microsoft does _not_ make this error, contrary to your claim.  It fixed the nomenclature used on the Explorer desktop years ago in Windows NT 5, as noted.  Calling these things "DOS prompts" is just plain wrong any way one slices it.  They are Windows NT console windows.  And CMD is nothing to do with DOS _at all_, as I, [Tim Hill](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc723564.aspx), and many other people explain.  Learn that this is an outright error that you are propounding.

Comment: @JdeBP Thanks for the correction of my misnomer. Assuming something instead of asking to be supplied is a different way of working, it's unprofessional, but it's working. Anyway, I just want to help.